# AWS CLI Config profile not found

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to login to AWS CLI, I first configured with this process: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/tutorial-ec2-ubuntu.html.

Then I ran export `AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=ken`, but, I then put my account number instead and now I get the and error message even if I just type `aws help`.

The message is:

```
botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (148244104581) could not be found
```

~/.aws/credentials:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ************
LAMWPQ aws_secret_access_key = ***********GFX
```

Comment: without posting the actual keys, what does your ~/.aws/credentials file look like ?

Comment: kenneth@kenneth-Inspiron-5558:~$ cat ~/.aws/credentials
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ************LAMWPQ
aws_secret_access_key = ***********GFX

Comment: your proflile there isn't [ken]

Comment: @Sirex consider improving your comment to an answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you give a profile name or change the default profile name you're effectively saying 'i want to use a named profile in my crednetials file'.

so what you've done here is said 'use the profile called 'ken' as my default, but your default profile is called 'default' not 'ken'.

Typically this ability is used to have profiles called 'dev' or 'prod' etc, and i'd advise making dev the 'default' as opposed to prod to avoid unexpected mishaps.

Comment: I appreicate it, You were right, thank you, Can I ask you, how can I upload documents into my buckets, so far reading the CLI S3 Reference Guide I have just been able to run aws s3 ls "and my bucket name" but I can't do cd, what would you recommend?

Comment: i recommend using a tool called 's3cmd' it becomes as easy as 's3cmd put my_file_name s3://my_bucketname/bucket/path. It'll also automatically reuse the same credentials file you just made. Installed with 'pip install s3cmd'

Comment: Nice!!!
Kenneth@kenneth-Inspiron-5558:~$ sudo pip install s3cmd
[sudo] password for kenneth:
/home/kenneth/.cache/pip/wheels/f8/61/e5/dd1029e23a94a40b995eab1a9e06a1cf874c7745a383af5034
Successfully built s3cmd python-magic
Installing collected packages: python-magic, s3cmd
Successfully installed python-magic-0.4.12 s3cmd-1.6.1