# The config profile (adminuser) could not be found

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have an IAM user `adminuser` which is in the `Administrators` group (having AdministratorAccess).

I have used `aws configure` to set up the settings.

**~/.aws/config**

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
output = json
```

**~/.aws/credentials**

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ************
aws_secret_access_key = ************
```

But when I run 
`aws lambda list-functions --profile adminuser`, it says

> The config profile (adminuser) could not be found

Once I run `export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=adminuser`, and run 
`aws lambda list-functions --profile adminuser` again, it shows:

> botocore.exceptions.ProfileNotFound: The config profile (adminuser)
>   could not be found

I read [AWS CLI Config profile not found](https://serverfault.com/questions/789734/aws-cli-config-profile-not-found). So I try to changed to

**~/.aws/config**

```
[adminuser]
region = us-east-1
output = json
```

**~/.aws/credentials**

```
[adminuser]
aws_access_key_id = ************
aws_secret_access_key = ************
```

and run `aws lambda list-functions --profile adminuser` again, then it shows:

> You must specify a region. You can also configure your region by
>   running "aws configure".

I also tried this like the [official AWS document demo](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-getting-started.html)

**~/.aws/config**

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
output = json

[adminuser]
region = us-east-1
output = json
```

**~/.aws/credentials**

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ************
aws_secret_access_key = ************

[profile adminuser]
aws_access_key_id = ************
aws_secret_access_key = ************
```

But still failed.

How can I run `aws lambda list-functions --profile adminuser` successfully? Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I finally succeed by using

**~/.aws/config**

```
[default]
region = us-east-1
output = json
```

**~/.aws/credentials**

```
[adminuser]          // <- here changes to adminuser
aws_access_key_id = ************
aws_secret_access_key = ************
region = us-east-1   // <- note this line
```

Comment: Thanks! I was working through the docs for aws-lambda and found the same issue. The AWS docs need some updating here.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using
 `aws lambda list-functions --profile adminuser` 
you can use
 `aws lambda list-functions --profile default`

and it will be done.

OR you may like to change "default" to "adminuser", that you have done.

This is not like the documentation is incorrect or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with Jenkins on windows, I copied .aws folder from my profile to system profile `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\` without changing Jenkins service i.e. Jenkins service runs on local system account. Then windows batch jobs on Jenkins fetches the same results as if we run in windows cmd. Moreover, I uninstalled the AWSCLI done by the pip3 method, used AWSCLI .msi type installation, hence resolved PATH issue error ( "aws command not found" during build)

Answer (score -1):

If you are using jenkins in windows please change log on user in windows service configuration. Restart the service. Should work.

Answer (score -2):

I was facing same issue, In my case config and credential files were not having read access. provided access chmod 755 for both files and issue resolved.

Comment: From a security point of view, giving 755 permission to files that have no need to be executed is horrible. And you say these files contains credentials ...